# How to separate a long object of integers into 2 columns in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

So I'm trying to clean up polygon data to make a map in tableau and I've got a column (wkt_polygon) made of a long list of longitudes and latitudes which I want to split into 2 separate long and lat columns. The problem is its an object and I'm struggling to convert it into a list.

you can see the object has brackets on the end and the long+lat is separated by a comma:
[image]

Comment: what kind of object is it? you can use type() to identify it.

Comment: Please edit your question according to the guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its a series object

Comment: so would i convert it to a list of tuples so I could unzip it?

Comment: can you provide the value of df.wkt_polygon[0] ? Is it like (lat long, lat long, ....) ? How many lat long are there in one tuple ?

Comment: i've realised this wont solve my bigger problem of making a map of the data, I've made a new question addressing this broader issue, thankyou though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372517/how-to-turn-wkt-data-into-a-map-i-can-further-analyse-on-tableau-python-or-othe